# Require git commits to come from *@mydomain.com

Tags: git, github

> I'm asking this question here since it seems like this is where [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions) is suggesting i post it. If this should not be posted on stackoverflow and should instead be posted somewhere else, please let me know.

I'm trying to enforce a branch permission on my github repository that will only allow new commits from users that have their author information configured with an email address from my domain.

i.e. "Only allow commits from users with email addresses ending in @mydomain.com"

This is to avoid developers with potentially misconfigured author information from making commits. We've had to fix our commit history several times due to this.

We do not have GitHub Enterprise so as far as I know we cannot use the pre-receive hooks to do this, unless they are also available outside GitHub Enterprise and I'm just not aware of it.

Is this feature available or are there any third party applications that would provider this feature?

I do not want to require each developer to configure a pre-commit hook, i would prefer if this were something i can configure remotely to simply reject commits that do not match the criteria.

Comment: pre-receive hooks are a base Git feature, but you must set up a central server, which is nontrivial.

Comment: @torek can you elaborate? From looking at GitHub's feature list it seems to say that only self hosted instances of GitHub Enterprise have access to pre-receive hooks.

Comment: I used to run a corporate Git server (pre-2010). We permitted only ssh based push initially and the git hooks ran as whatever user did the push; then we switched to Gitolite, which has its own front end system and uses its own pre-receive and update hooks, but give you additional hooks. It's all in there, out of the box, it's just that there is no cohesive control for it. (Gitolite provides some of that cohesive control stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide this natively.  However, like most custom checks, you can implement this with a CI check against pull requests.  If you require CI checks to pass before merge, you can check that every commit in a range matches your domain with a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

! git log --no-merges --format="%ae %ce" $1 | grep -vE '@mydomain.com .*@mydomain.com'
```

and then pass in the range of commits as the argument.

As you mentioned, you could do this with a pre-receive hook if you were using GitHub Enterprise Server, but pre-receive hooks aren't supported with the cloud version.  If you're using your own Git server (which I suspect you're not by your tags), then you can indeed use a pre-receive hook there.